More advanced way to see that there are three smooth homotopy classes on $\mathcal I$?
Background:
We start by posing a simple to state geometric optimization question: What is the largest surface of revolution with constant positive Gaussian curvature that can be embedded in $X^3=[0,1]^3$ with a pair of antipodal corners as cone points? It can be shown that there is a unique surface solution to this question. Therefore, replicating this surface three more times within $X^3$ where each copy is paired with distinct antipodal cone points, we get the Interface construction, which is the union of these four surfaces, or leaves.
Let the Interface Construction be denoted by $ \mathcal{I} $. Given the symmetry and unique structural constraints of $ \mathcal{I} $, we expect its associated $\Gamma$-set—denoted $ \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma} $—to be unique and particularly rigid among all possible $\Gamma$-sets within this construction framework. This uniqueness and rigidity arise from the geometrically constrained configuration of $ \mathcal{I} $, which imposes minimization of variation in the structure.
$\Gamma$-set of $\mathcal I$:
To rigorously characterize $ \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma} $, we define it as follows:
$$
\mathcal{I}_{\Gamma} := \bigcup_{j=1}^3 \left( \mathcal{I} \cap \{x_j = 1/2\} \right),
$$
where $ \{x_1, x_2, x_3\} $ are the standard coordinates on $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ and the planes $ \{x_j = 1/2\}$ represent the intersections of $ \mathcal{I} $ with the coordinate planes $ x = \frac{1}{2}, y = \frac{1}{2}, $ and $ z = \frac{1}{2} $. The set $ \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma} $ is thus the union of three loops, each loop being the intersection of $ \mathcal{I} $ with one of the coordinate planes. This construction partitions $ \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma} $ into three distinct components:
$$
\mathcal{I}_{\Gamma} = \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma,1} \cup \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma,2} \cup \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma,3},
$$
where $ \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma,j} := \mathcal{I} \cap \{x_j = 1/2\} $.
Smooth Embeddings of $S^1$ onto $\mathcal I$:
Let $ \text{Emb}(S^1, \mathcal{I}) $ denote the space of all smooth embeddings of $ S^1 $ into $ \mathcal{I} $. Each embedding $ f_\gamma: S^1 \to \mathcal{I} $ is a smooth, injective map that traces out a simple closed loop on $ \mathcal{I} $, representing a primitive cycle. Two embeddings $ f_1, f_2: S^1 \to \mathcal{I} $ are considered equivalent if they are smoothly isotopic, meaning there exists a smooth family of embeddings connecting $ f_1 $ to $ f_2 $.
We define the space of all marked structures as:
$$
\mathcal{S}_{\mathcal{I}}^{\text{Emb}} = \{ (\mathcal{I}, f_\gamma) \mid f_\gamma \in \text{Emb}(S^1, \mathcal{I}) \}.
$$
This space is a discrete and finite moduli space of surfaces, where each point represents a surface $ \mathcal{I} $ marked with an embedded primitive cycle.
Furthermore, these embeddings correspond to homotopy classes in the fundamental group $ \pi_1(\mathcal{I}) $, where each embedded loop represents an element of $ \pi_1(\mathcal{I}) $.
Takeaway:
This proves that $ \mathcal{I}_{\Gamma,j} \in \pi_1(\mathcal{I})$. Note that considering $\mathcal I_{\Gamma}$ and spherically triangular subsets as closed loops fails to qualify as a smooth embedding. Therefore the class is exhausted at three.
Question:

Is there another (perhaps more advanced way) to see that there are exactly three smooth embeddings, $f_{\gamma}$? Here's a model, pictured with the three (different colored) embedded homotopy classes on $\mathcal I$:


A Related question, which asks about vector bundles and holonomy on $\mathcal I_{\Gamma}$.
